# Execute the output of previous command line

Tags: linux, shell

I need to execute the result of a previous command, but I don't know how I can process.

I have a first command that returns an instruction to log in to the server and then I want to execute it just after.

my-first-command returns: docker login ...

For example:

`> my-first-comnand | execute the result of my-first-command`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it I believe.

> my-first-command | bash

Comment: Thanks Hexagenic, it works   we can do this  **my-first-command | sh**   also

Comment: @user7544861, those aren't identical. `sh` has a more restrictive language available than `bash`.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html for the places where this differs even if `/bin/sh` is a hardlink to `bash` -- if your `/bin/sh` is provided by a different shell such as `ash` or `dash`, there will be even more changes.

Answer (score 1):

I use `$(!!)` for this. As Charles points out, this may not be what everyone wants to do, but it works for me and suits my purpose better than the other answer.

```
$ find ./ -type f -name "some.sh" 
$ $(!!)
```

`!!` is a variable that holds the last command, and putting into `$( )` makes it get executed.

This is also useful for taking other actions on the output, since `$( )` is treated as a variable.

Comment: That's **rerunning** the prior command. If it's slow/expensive, it can take a long time, and the output may not be exactly the same the second time around.

Comment: It's also different in terms of how it parses commands. If the output was `printf '%s\n' "foo bar"`, the result of piping it to a shell or running it with `eval` is different from expanding it unquoted -- the former two options print a single line with `foo bar`, the latter prints one line with the string `""foo` and a second line with the string `""bar"`. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Very good points! Personally, I prefer rerunning the command since I generally want to check the output before I run it. As per the differences in expansion, I'd hope that we'd be imagining a different solution for a use-case like that, altogether.

Comment: If your `some.sh` is located in a directory with spaces, you're in a use case like that already. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most handy way is to use backticks `` `your_command` `` to execute your sub-command inline and immediately use output in your main command.

Example:

```
`find ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/* -d 0 | tail -1`/zipalign -f 4 ./app-release-unsigned.apk ./app-release.apk
```

In this example I firstly `find` the correct directory from where I will execute zipalign. There could be several directories as in my case (find returns two directories) so I getting last one using `tail`. And then I'm executing zipalign directly using previous result as path to correct zipalign binary.